Android Studio Ladybug(2024.2.2) taking too much time in building/importing the project
I am facing this issue where my android studio is taking way more time in importing the project into the studio.
I have tried by upgrading the heap size, the memory allocation size but it seems nothing is working for me.
Also I tired adding these lines inside the gradle.properties file.
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true

Adding the build.gradle here
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    //id 'newrelic'
    id 'hypersdk.plugin'

}
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
//    compileSdkVersion 34

    defaultConfig {
        compileSdk 34
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 118
        versionName "12.4"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    flavorDimensions "api"
    productFlavors {
        staging {
            buildConfigField("String", "API_BASE_URL", API_BASE_URL)
            buildConfigField("String", "API_CHECKSUM_URL", CHECKSUM_URL)
        }
        production {
            buildConfigField("String", "API_BASE_URL", API_BASE_URL)
            buildConfigField("String", "API_CHECKSUM_URL", CHECKSUM_URL)
        }
    }
    ndkVersion = "23.2.8568313"

//    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
//    buildToolsVersion '33.0.2'
//    buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'
    dependencies {

        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
        implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
        //Google Map
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.0.0'
//        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
        //Retrofit
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
        //Gson
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.2'

        //Lottie animation
        implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:5.1.1'
        //Glide Image Loader
        //implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
        //implementation 'com.github.corouteam:GlideToVectorYou:v2.0.0'
        implementation 'com.github.2coffees1team:GlideToVectorYou:v2.0.0'

        //Dexter for run time permission
        implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'

        //OK Http
//        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'

        //payumoney sdk
//        implementation 'in.payu:payu-checkout-pro:2.0.19'
        implementation 'in.payu:payu-checkout-pro:2.3.1'
        //scanner
        implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.2.0') { transitive = false }
        // Not upgrade, because otherwise will work only on api > 24
        implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
        //charts
        implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
        //Omni BLE lock lib
        implementation 'com.omni.support:ble:1.7.4'
        //pin view
        implementation 'com.github.aabhasr1:OtpView:v1.1.2-ktx' // kotlin
        //pdf view
        implementation 'com.github.afreakyelf:Pdf-Viewer:v1.0.7'
        //implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.20.0")
        //zoho
//    implementation 'com.zoho.salesiq:mobilisten:4.2.9'
//    implementation 'com.zoho.salesiq:mobilisten:4.4.0'
        implementation 'com.zoho.salesiq:mobilisten:5.1.0'

        //Firebase
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:24.0.0'
        implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.0.0"))
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'

        //Record Video
        implementation 'com.github.MasayukiSuda:CameraRecorder-android:v0.1.5'
        implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.1'
        //in-app review by google
        implementation 'com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.1'

        //for test purpose using this sdk
        //implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:6.6.0'

        implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'
        
        //mapbox sdk
        implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:11.3.1'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:7.0.0'
//        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:6.12.0'


        //old
        /*implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.8.0'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.1.0'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:6.7.0'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:6.7.0'*/

        //new paytm sdk
//    implementation 'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.6.13'
//    implementation 'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.6.15'
        implementation 'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.6.17'

        //tooltip
        implementation 'com.tomergoldst.android:tooltips:1.1.1'

        //relic lib
        //implementation 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:6.9.2'

        //Auto fetch OTP
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'

        //Step Progress bar for payment integration
        implementation 'com.anton46:stepsview:0.0.2'

        //For Handel thread
        implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'

        //facebook sdk
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'

        //For Image Picker
        implementation 'io.github.ParkSangGwon:tedimagepicker:1.4.2'

        //For Branch.io (deep link)
//        implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:5.8.0'

    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

Still I found no luck with it.
Can any one help me out with this?


bro.. are you importing the lord of rings trilogy.!!. joke aside,, can you look into the Build analyzer -> Tasks impacting build duration.. you'll get a better idea on what holding up

@AllwiN Is it the extended version? haha

@Jay I guess this particular version got multiple ending..

Does this happen with every project or just a specific one? How about when the project was imported, does doing a clean/rebuild is also problematic?

@tyg No only to this specific project.

If @AllwiN's first comment doesn't help you figure out the issue yourself you need to provide a [mre] for us to reproduce the issue.

It's not helping, to post screenshots with truncated warnings, no build.gradle, no nothing.
That's merely a complaint alike "it's not working".

Just kill the Java Gradle process and restart Android Studio. Does the project build if you execute ./gradlew assembledebug on command-line outside of AS?
